# Direct product and homomorphism for $f : X \to Y_1 \times Y_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've got some idea from https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Direct_Product_of_Group_Homomorphisms_is_Homomorphism.

And I made the statement below by expanding the general case either groups  or rings.

Statement)  Let the $X$ and $Y_i$ be groups(or rings)

Say homomorphism $f_i : X \to Y_i  $

$\forall$ homomorphism, $f : X \to Y_1 \times Y_2, \exists$ homomorpshims $f_1$ and $f_2$ s.t. $f = f_1 \times f_2$

(Equivalently, The number of the $f$ = the number of the $f_1$ $\times$ the number of the $f_2$)

---

Well... at least I've looked those, it is true for me. But I can't guess the things right or not.

If the statement is true, Is the proof method same with the methods in above link?

If the statement is false, Please let me know some counterexample, Cause I haven't found it yet.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you can use that it is both a product and a coproduct and then you should be done. I.e. you got 2 projections giving you $f_i$ and then the universal property gives a unique morphism which by uniqueness must be the same as your starting morphism. I hope I understand your statement correctly. i.e. that every morphism into a direct product consists of 2 morphisms into the respective factors

Comment: If $\pi_i:Y_1\times Y_2\to Y_i$ is the projection map then $f_i=\pi_i\circ f$.

Comment: @Enkidu, yes you already got what I meant :)